# Django: using objects.get(), objects.filter(), etc. raises error

Tags: django-models

I checked out a project with code that worked on my colleague's machine, but on mine it gives an error with objects.get(), saying: "undefined variable from import: get". All other methods for objects got the same error.

What is missing in my environment?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: updating from Eclipse Kepler to Luna did the trick.